# net use F: \\localhost\C$\ASC_Drives\F shows as Disconected Network Drive

Tags: windows, networking, hard-drive, mount

For a in-house software I need two additional drives on my local VM. To simplify the whole thing, I created a directory `C:\ASC_Drives\F` and mapped it to F:

```
net use F: \\localhost\C$\ASC_Drives\F /persistent:yes
net use G: \\localhost\C$\ASC_Drives\G /persistent:yes
```

After the reboot, I can enter F: and G: and see its content but windows complain that the drives are not mounted:

[image: Disconneted Network Drive]

How to make it "connected"? In-house software detects the status changes of the drive through [DAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct-access_storage_device).

It looks to me that the problem is that I use `localhost` and I should use `127.0.0.1` instead. But how can I delete the drive now so I can reconnect it through 127.0.0.1?

```
C:\Users\Administrator>net use F: /delete
The network connection could not be found.

More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 2250.
```

If I disconnect it through Contextual Menu:

[image: This network connection does not exist]

Comment: Do you see them in Windows Explorer? If you do, right-click and choose "Disconnect".

Answer (score 1):

Try using "subst" instead.  MUCH simpler mechanism.

```
subst F: C:\ASC_Drives\F
```

It's been around since DOS 3.1 and still works!

[Microsoft help for 'subst'](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/subst)

8^)

Comment: Indeed it does. Can I make it work after restart (the drive was not reconnected). Do you know, how to drop a disconnected drive?

Comment: Does this help? https://www.digitalcitizen.life/how-delete-mapped-drives-windows-7